# XCode 7 Compilation Error with Swift

Tags: swift, compilation, compiler-errors, xcode7

Can someone help me fix this issue?  I added another ViewController and modally linked it to the original view controller.  It originally worked, but I ran it again because I made change in text and now it will not compile.  I deleted all constraints and deleted the "button" that it says is not correctly linked.

```
2015-10-26 00:48:43.611 XXXX[5790:2031206] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15ce8dac0 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x15ce2e050]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x15ce694a0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15ce8e630 'UIInputWindowController-top' V:|-(0)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x15ce2e050]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x15ce694a0 )>")

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
```

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-10-26 00:48:44.446 XXXXX[5790:2031206] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<XXXXXX.CreateAnAccountViewController 0x15cd1fd40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key SignUpLabel.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x185198f5c 0x19a67ff80 0x185198c1c 0x18600f534 0x18aa4f9b8 0x18ab9b4b8 0x1850c2acc 0x18ab99ea0 0x18aa52cfc 0x18a827ea8 0x18a6ef258 0x18a6ef1b0 0x18af713a4 0x18aa3705c 0x18aa5c508 0x18aa5f294 0x18a7e60c0 0x18adea5d8 0x18adddcf8 0x18adddafc 0x18addddc4 0x18a7263e4 0x18a726360 0x18a70ec88 0x18a725c78 0x18a7258a8 0x18a71eadc 0x18a6efa2c 0x18a6edf18 0x1851505a4 0x185150038 0x18514dd38 0x18507cdc0 0x190518088 0x18a756f60 0x1000d56e4 0x19ae9e8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an outlet in your view that is connected to a label (`SignUpLabel`) in your class that is not found.

Either your File's owner is not set to be your ViewController or you have deleted/renamed the label in your class and need to reset the outlet in your view.

You also have an error with your constraints but that shouldn't contribute to the crash.